# Map is rendering too slow

Tags: c++, sdl

I have a basic 20x20 array that stores the map for my game. It either has a 1 or 0 to say a path and a non path. When I draw it on the screen, It seems to take to long to draw one at a time and looks like a snake is being loaded on the screen. I need them drawing faster.

## Set up the screen array

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sizeOfArray; j++)
        {
            if (LevelOne[i][j]==0)//Path
            {
                screenChunks[i][j].Set(i*40,j*40,"Path.bmp", screen);
            }
            if (LevelOne[i][j]==1)//Wall
            {
                screenChunks[i][j].Set(i*40,j*40,"Wall.bmp", screen);
            }
            if (LevelOne[i][j]==2) //Hero
            {
                screenChunks[i][j].Set(i*40,j*40,"Hero.bmp", screen);
            }
        }
    }
```

## Draw the sprites

```
for(int i=0; i<sizeOfArray; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<sizeOfArray; j++)
        {
            screenChunks[i][j].Draw();
        }
    }

    //Dynamically drawn each time
    SDL_FillRect(screen,0,0);

    //Hero Start Position
    hero.Draw();

    SDL_Delay(60);
```

## Sprite.cpp Draw Method

```
void Sprite::Draw()
{
SDL_Rect offset;

//Give the offsets to the rectangle
offset.x = PosX;
offset.y = PosY;

//Blit the surface
SDL_BlitSurface( sprite, NULL, Screen, &offset );

Height = offset.h;
Width = offset.w;

SDL_UpdateRect(Screen, 0,0,0,0);
```

}

## Sprite Setter

```
void Sprite::Set(int posX, int posY, string imagePath, SDL_Surface *screen)
{
PosX = posX;
PosY = posY;
ImagePath = imagePath;
Screen = screen;

if(ImagePath == "")
    return;

char * writable = new char [ImagePath.size()+1];
strcpy (writable, ImagePath.c_str());

temp = SDL_LoadBMP(writable);
sprite = SDL_DisplayFormat(temp);
SDL_FreeSurface(temp);
// free the string after using it
delete[] writable;
}
```

Comment: It's only 400 sprites so it shouldn't be too slow. Is that `    SDL_Delay(60);` supposed to be there? Sprite Batching might be helpful but the problem is probably somewhere else with so few sprites.

Comment: The delay happens after the full array is rendered. i could make it 1000 jsut to see the final image for 1 second

Comment: Why not just draw as fast as possible? Have you timed how long the loop takes? How many miliseconds?

Comment: What does your profiler tell you? If you haven't used a profiler, get one and do so. It's far better than guesswork at determining where performance issues are in your code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loading an image from disk every time you need to draw it is a bad idea. Terrible, in fact. Try loading once and reusing it.

Also, please have a look at calling `SDL_UpdateRect(Screen, 0,0,0,0);` on every sprite draw...

BTW, if you're doing the whole "writable" thing because `ImagePath` is an `std::string` and `SDL_LoadBMP` accepts `char*`, then you should google the c_str() method.

Comment: Ok cool. Ill try that. How can i reuse the image instead of reloading it? Store it as a private in my Sprite.h?

Comment: SDL_LoadBMP(c_str(ImagePath)) Like this?

Comment: For instance. I don't see where the `temp` variable is declared, so maybe you are already doing that. As for c_str()... just search C++ c_str() for an example, ok? :)

Comment: temp is stored as a private variable

Comment: However I load the image for each sprite. Is there a way to load it once for all images of type wall? Should I make a class called wall to inherit from this?

Comment: I have done this and It does not help. The thing still loads too slow

Comment: I don't know what you did. If you did an instance variable, then indeed it would slow for the first time, then faster. The sensible solution would be to load it only once (for instance in a global variable).

Comment: The loading has been extracted out of the loop and the loop now only draws the images and it is still slow. Loading is not the issue here. But good advice anyways. +1

Comment: @JonathanO one more question - why are calling `SDL_UpdateRect(Screen, 0,0,0,0);` with every Sprite::Draw()?

Answer (score 1):

For loading images only once, check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1729699/how-do-i-correctly-use-sdl-freesurface-when-dealing-with-a-vector-of-surfaces which introduces the idea of an image_cache.

I've expanded on this on my blog [here](http://sednihp.wordpress.com/2012/06/02/111/) and then again once I'd updated my design to break up the class into smaller more manageable pieces [here](http://sednihp.wordpress.com/2012/12/15/introducing-fontcache-textcache-and-mediacache/)